# Play mp4 video in Internet Explorer 11 with security level set to high

Tags: video, internet-explorer, mp4

I am using the html5  tag to embed mp4 videos on a site. They play well in all browsers except on IE-11 but only when the security level is set to high (if security level downgrade to medium video plays fine). It seems IE disables flash, javascripts and some other components when the security level is set to high. Due to security policies I cannot change this security setting so I am looking at any other options to embed videos on IE-11?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the default level? If it's not High then clearly the user (or an admin) changed it deliberately, and thus supposedly knows the consequences of doing so. I wouldn't worry too much about figuring out a way to push the video to such users when they don't want it.

Comment: Default level is high and is set by default by the company policy so users cannot change it.

Comment: This is the same company you work for, or a client? In either case if they want to view the videos in IE then they have to change the security policy.

Comment: They are a client so that's why they are not keen to make any infrastructure changes.... we did advice changing the security settings or trusting our site were the only options.......we just wanted to explore if there were any other workarounds but I guess there none.  Appreciate your input and time @Karan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Security Zone Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537178(v=vs.85).aspx) are implemented in IE-6 and since then there is not much changed.

I believe the HTML5 object tag is rendered trough the `URLACTION_ACTIVEX_DYNSRC_VIDEO_AND_ANIMATION` zone which is blocked in the `High Template`. The same goes for JavaScript and stuff.

An overview of all the zones you will find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537178(v=vs.85).aspx)

Maybe its an solution to create an own security template, and just enable the things you need for loading an video.

As far I know there are no work-around, if there is its a huge bug in the security of IE.

Comment: Thanks @S.Visser, I was suspecting there weren't any workarounds. The company admin people are not keen to change their security templates but I guess there are no other options here. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This solution just resolved hours of grief for me.  It was indeed the security settings in the browser.  Thank you.